# CentOS 7 fails to boot after update and restart

Tags: linux, networking, boot, centos, centos-7

I simply updated my CentOS 7 laptop (new kernel update) and not it fails to boot. Looking at the logs it print on the screen, I could see an error:

`Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.`

On googling, I could understand it is something related to Network Manager, but I couldn't figure it out a solution.

Now basically, I can't boot into the shell. But I have CentOS disk with which I can boot to rescue mode.

Is there a way it can be fixed (other than a fresh install) ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be running DHCP, in which case you will have to kill that process. It could also be an error in your network configuration setting also (like using 10.0.0.x when you're on a 192.168.x.x network).

See this older answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/660210/cant-start-centos-7-network-service) for more details

Comment: Thanks. But how can I check this or kill dhcp if I can't boot into the machine?